# No appropriate font found using MigraDoc to create a PDF on Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, pdfsharp, migradoc

I'm trying to create a pdf using MigraDoc. Here's a list of the libraries that I'm using:

- MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel
- MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Tables
- MigraDoc.Rendering

It throws me an error on `printer.RenderDocument()`. Code below

```
private async Task SavePDF()
        {
            filePath = emulatorFolderPath + "/Signed/" + _reportInformationViewModel.SelectedClient.Username + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd_MM_yyyy HH-mm") + ".pdf";
            MigraDocRendering.PdfDocumentRenderer printer = new MigraDocRendering.PdfDocumentRenderer
            {
                Document = document
            };
            printer.RenderDocument();
            printer.PdfDocument.Save(filePath);
        }
```

PS: I don't need to use a private font.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Xamarin port of PDFsharp, but I think you have to use private fonts. In MigraDoc only use the private fonts supported by your IFontResolver. implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved by implementing `IFontResolver`
I've added a folder `Fonts` that contains Open-Sans font.
I've created a folder `Helpers` that contains a class called `GenericFontResolver`:

```
public class GenericFontResolver : IFontResolver
    {
        public string DefaultFontName => "OpenSans";

        public byte[] GetFont(string faceName)
        {
            if (faceName.Contains(DefaultFontName))
            {
                var assembly = typeof(ReportPreviewAndSignatureViewModel).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
                var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream($"PDFDemo.Fonts.{faceName}.ttf");

                using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    var bytes = default(byte[]);

                    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        reader.BaseStream.CopyTo(ms);
                        bytes = ms.ToArray();
                    }

                    return bytes;
                }
            }
            else
                return GetFont(DefaultFontName);
        }

        public FontResolverInfo ResolveTypeface(string familyName, bool isBold, bool isItalic)
        {
            var fontName = string.Empty;

            switch (familyName)
            {
                case "Open Sans":
                case "OpenSans":
                    fontName = "OpenSans";

                    if (isBold && isItalic)
                        fontName = $"{fontName}-BoldItalic";
                    else if (isBold)
                        fontName = $"{fontName}-Bold";
                    else if (isItalic)
                        fontName = $"{fontName}-Italic";
                    else
                        fontName = $"{fontName}-Regular";

                    return new FontResolverInfo(fontName);
                default:
                    break;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Then, on the constructor of the class that needs the font I've added:

`GlobalFontSettings.FontResolver = new GenericFontResolver();`

Then, when I'm creating the table you must add:

```
Style style = document.Styles["Normal"];
style.Font.Name = "OpenSans";
```

Comment: I'm trying your code with the following Chinese font: `noto-sans-mono-sc.otf` and get the same **no appropriate font** error. The font has been tested elsewhere and works fine. I've tested your code with other ttf files with no problem. Do you know why this may be failing on the Chinese font?

Comment: Maybe because of the different encoding

Comment: Would be able to help me understand more on that or how I could use that knowledge to resolve this problem?

Comment: I don't use Xamarin anymore. I suggest you to use another programming language ;)